# order in excel file following multiple conditions

Tags: excel

In my excel file I want to use the rank function
this is my file:
[image]

first I have to order by note column 'H' in my file, then by date_recrutement column 'G' and finally by date_naissance column 'F'

using only one column to get the order , I know how to do it:

```
= rang(h2;h2:h245)
```

but here I have to use three columns!

Comment: I cannot find `rang` function in my Excel 2016.  Is it a new Excel built-in function?

Comment: rang is used for excel frensh version.
try rank for the english version

Comment: So your final rank would be 4, 6, 2, 5, 1, 7, 3?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I have more these rows. But if we consider only these rows , that's ok :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all data/table > r-click > Sort > Custom sort .

Then put is you preferred sorting configuration there.. Done.

Hope it helps. (:

p/s: if the rank function works, then just creating a new table each time one rank criteria is applied is also a workable solution.