# How to rank based on 3 different ranks?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 different rankings in my excel.
I need to create overall ranking.

If there are no duplicate values on rank 1 => overall should looks exactly like rank 1.
If there are duplicate values on rank 1 (like on image) => overall rank should check rank 1 and see which of these duplicates have higher rank in rank 2. (same with rank 2 and 3)

[image]

So in this case overall should be: (from top) 2;1;3

Is it possible to make using excel functions?

Comment: you can use a helper column to construct a combined number/pseudo-rank (using multiples of 10 and also taking into account max number of digits in ranks) and then get overall ranking based on it. in the given example, the combined will be 132, 113, 321, then the resulting rank will be 2, 1, 3

Comment: What if rank 3 in second row will be two digits number? Combined will be 132 1111 321, and the resulting rank wont be 2,1,3, but 1,3,2.
There can be plenty rows

Comment: that is why I said you need to take into account max number of digits in a rank. i,.e. if you have more than 9 and less than 100 elements to rank, the max number of digits in a rank is 2, then the combined helper will have 3*2 - 6 digits

Comment: any luck on the tries ?

Comment: I changed my concept a little and made it with excel-built in sorting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to make using excel functions?

My straight answer (with my very small excel knowledge) : No.

Is there methods to get there : Yes.

### Method one (GUI) :

[excel-built in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58834989/order-in-excel-file-following-multiple-conditions/59085804#59085804)

### Method two  (manual, expandable, (my personal favorite) less function dependent) :

Since you have quite a number of column/rows involved, understanding an expandable method should do then. The main sequence is : (1) put a weight , apply to (each) list > (2) generate product > sort/rank .

Step 1 :

- Assuming your data is located at A2:C4, in A6 put : `=1/COLUMN()` and drag till C6.
- in A7 put : `=A2*A$6` and drag till C9.

Step 2 :

- In E7 put : `=SUM(A7:C7)` and drag till E9.

Step 3 :

- In G7 : `=RANK.AVG(E7,$E$7:$E$9,1)` and drag till G9.

And that is your desired rank.

The idea : since the 'tie' in the 1st column is determined by the next column, then applying less weight as the column number raise is suitable (you can always use any number you want, as long as it answers the 'tie-braker' requirement). In the end, the row with the least weight will raise up as the smallest number.

Please share if it works/not/understandable. /(^_^)

Answer (score 0):

Try in `E2`:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($E$1:E1,SUMPRODUCT(--(($A$2:$A$4+$B$2:$B$4+$C$2:$C$4)<SUM(A2:C2)))+1)>0,SUMPRODUCT(--(($A$2:$A$4+$B$2:$B$4+$C$2:$C$4)<SUM(A2:C2)))+2,SUMPRODUCT(--(($A$2:$A$4+$B$2:$B$4+$C$2:$C$4)<SUM(A2:C2)))+1)
```

Drag down.